# How to generate a Transparency "Gradient" Shader?(Eevee)

Tags: shaders, transparency

Using the  setup below ,a transparent gradient shader does not get generated.

How to generate a Tranparency "Gradient"  Shader in Eevee?

[image]

---

> UPDATE 1

---

[image]

Tried the below 2 solutions by @Moonboots but was not getting the same result.  Also checked switching Blend mode to Alpha-Blend and unchecking 'Show Backface' ,but not getting transparency.What's missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using EEVEE, you need to change the _Blend Mode_ of the material. It's in the material properties tab. Change to anything other than _Opaque_ (I find Alpha-Blend works nicely for most situations).

Comment: please share your last file

Comment: Blend file uploaded(plz find in above question)

Comment: Gradient Node has to be connected first to the alpha socket and then the Color ramp node  inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your node organization, in my opinion you should choose between the alpha and the transparent solution, which would give the *ColorRamp* plugged into the *Alpha* socket:

[image]

or the *ColorRamp* into the factor of the *Mix Shader* between the *Principled BSDF* and the *Transparent*:

[image]

Also, maybe deactivate the material *Show Backface* option?